# How can I perform a meta-analysis on variables which are not normally distributed?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am working on a project to estimate a radiation protection value called DDREF which is the ratio of two regression coefficients.  Specifically:

$DDREF$ $=$ $a/B$

where

$E$ ~ $a*D+B*D^2$

$D$ is dose and $E$ is some outcome, like survival.  $a$ and $B$ are coefficients determined by regression.

I have independent estimates of DDREF from many studies and I would like to combine them into a single estimate.  But I'm not sure how to do this because the ratio of two regression coefficients is not normally distributed.  Does anyone know how to perform a meta analysis on variables that are [ratio distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution)?  Or perhaps its better to ask the more general question how do I apply a meta-analysis to produce a central estimate from variables which are not normally distributed?

Comment: Do the estimates of a, b or DDREF have a standard error associated with them in the studies?

Comment: a and b have standard error.  DDREF is the ratio of a and b so it is not normally distributed.  So it probably has some standard error, but its hard to interpret it.

Comment: Does DDREF  =  a/B represents E. If so, you appear to be interested in structural equation modeling for a meta-analysis.

Comment: "Does DDREF = a/B represents E" not sure what you mean by "represents"?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you should be able to do so by using the (natural) logarithms and combining across studies using the generic inverse-variance method. I don't have a reference off the top of my head, but this would the same method used for poisson distributed data (e.g. rate data) (http://handbook.cochrane.org/chapter_9/9_4_8_meta_analysis_of_counts_and_rates.htm).

Hope this helps.